# Erlang, get applications from boot file

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am trying to use `hiera_server` to configure my erlang nodes. Idea is following. I want to write some script (language doesn't matter), which detects list of applications that will be started in erlang node. Then script obtains configuration from `hiera_server` and generates `*.config` file for certain node.
Question is how my script, looking to erlang release, can determine, which applications will be started in node? My suggestion is to inspect `*.boot` file somehow. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own. `*.boot`-file is binary representation of erlang bootscript (which named `*.script`). Format of boot script is covered in erlang documentation, manpage `script(4)`.